# create a php that can display the date of today and the one in 6 days

Tags: php, date, cron

I've got this php file :

```
<?php
echo "wednesday = 10 dec au 16 dec";
?>
```

I manually change it every wednesday (next wednesday, it will be `"wednesday = 17 dec au 23 dec";`)

I want to put a cron job for this, but I need to know how can I do to let the php calculate the date of today (the cron job will be schedule every wednesday) and 6 days later with the format that I had.

So something like

```
$thisWed = date('d  M');
$nextWed_day = date("d")+6;
$nextWed_month = date("M"); 
echo "$thisWed au $nextWed_day  $nextWed_month";
```

(but how if `$nextWed_month` have to change because `$thisWed`  is the 29 or 30 ??)

Any idea how to simply do that ?

Comment: use the `date()` function, here's the legend http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: Thx . I've edited my post as I used your link. But now, last question, how can manage the "next wednesday" if it changes month ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About title:
today => `date('d')`; 
6 days futher => `date('d', strtotime('+6 days'))`.

About your body text (sorry if I didn't get it right):

Next wednesday => 
`date('d', strtotime('next wednesday'))`.

Src:
[strtotime ref](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) / [date ref](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).